# Why is the output of these two programs different in C?

Tags: c

Program 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    float x = 0.1;
    if (x == 0.1)
        printf("IF");
    else if (x == 0.1f)
        printf("ELSE IF");
    else
    printf("ELSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Program 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main{
    float x = 0.5;
    if (x == 0.5)
        printf("IF");
    else if (x == 0.5f) 
        printf("ELSE IF");
    else
        printf("ELSE");
    return 0;
}
```

First program Output: ELSE IF
Second program Output: IF

Both programs are quite similar.But outputs are different.Why?

Comment: Possibly due to floating point precision errors. Using `==` to compare floats is not a good idea.

Comment: If it's C, why did you tag the question [tag:c++]? That is a most peculiar thing to do.

Comment: I'm more susprised that I can't find any `-O` or `-f` flag to make the first program output `"IF"`. After all, compilers support all sort of other unsafe optimization flags.

Comment: Omitting the `f` makes your literal number a `double`. A float may not be exactly equal to the "same" value as represented by a double.